# Replace null values based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, null

So I'm working on a dataset on Kaggle named netflix-movies-and-tv-shows. I'm currently on some data cleansing tasks and wanted to find the null values in the dataframe.

Let's say I have got a dataframe that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

all_data = {
    "person_id": [7782, 28692],
    "id": ["tm82169", "tm17823"],
    "name": ["John G.Avildsen", "Randal Kleiser"],
    "character": [np.nan, np.nan],
    "role": ["DIRECTOR", "ACTOR"]
}
index_labels = [1,2]
df = pd.DataFrame(all_data,index=index_labels)
print(df)
```

Now I want to replace the null values in the "character" column with something like:
If role is "ACTOR", then character = 'figurant'
If role is "DIRECTOR", then character = 'director'

I was able to find some solutions:

```
mask = (all_data['role'] == 'ACTOR')
all_data.loc[all_data['character'].isnull() & mask, 'character'] = 'figurant'
all_data.head(250)
```

OR:

```
all_data['character'] = all_data['character'].fillna('figurant').where(all_data['role'] == "ACTOR")
all_data.head(250)
```

However, I struggled to make the code work for both conditions.

I also tried the for loop with if-else condition:

```
for i in all_data['role']:
    if i == "ACTOR":
        all_data['character'].fillna('figurant')
    elif i == "DIRECTOR":
        all_data['character'].fillna('director') 
all_data.head(50)
```

But this turns out to only apply on "ACTOR". The null value of those who are "DIRECTOR" remain null.

I'm just a beginner in the python world, forgive me if the question may sound basic.

Thank you guys!

Comment: I think I accidentally chose something. I didn't mean to unaccept your answer. I'm kinda confused with all the functions here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a mapping dict to fill missing values:

```
dmap = {'DIRECTOR': 'director', 'ACTOR': 'figurant'}
df['character'] = df['character'].fillna(df['role'].map(dmap))
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   person_id       id             name character      role
1       7782  tm82169  John G.Avildsen  director  DIRECTOR
2      28692  tm17823   Randal Kleiser  figurant     ACTOR
```